# ONline exam timer with Javascript PHP MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, timer

The following code is for an online exam. When the user is done and had clicked the Get result button, the user will be redirected to the results page. Now the problem is it won't send to the results page.

This code is functioning properly

```
echo "<div class=\"module form-module\">";
echo "<form name=myfm class=form method=post id=myfm action=quiz.php>";
echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";
$n=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
echo "<tR><td><span class=style2>Question ".  $n .": $row[2]</style><br><br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=ans value=1>&nbsp;$row[3]<br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=ans value=2>&nbsp;$row[4]<br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=ans value=3>&nbsp;$row[5]<br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=ans value=4>&nbsp;$row[6]<br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=ans value=5>&nbsp;$row[7]<br>";
if($_SESSION[qn]<mysql_num_rows($rs)-1)
echo "<tr><td><br><input type=submit class=button id=submit name=submit value='Next Question'></form></div>";
else
echo "<tr><td><input type=submit id=submit class=button name=submit value='Get Result'></form></div>";
```

when the user is finished, it will go to this process

```
if($submit=='Next Question' && isset($ans))
{
        mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
        $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs); 
        mysql_query("insert into mst_useranswer(sess_id, test_id, que_des, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,ans5,true_ans,your_ans) values ('".session_id()."', $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$row[8]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());
        if($ans==$row[8])
        {
                    $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
        }
        $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
}
else if($submit=='Get Result' && isset($ans))
{
        mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
        $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs); 
        mysql_query("insert into mst_useranswer(sess_id, test_id, que_des, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,ans5,true_ans,your_ans) values ('".session_id()."', $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$row[8]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());
        if($ans==$row[8])
        {
                    $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
        }
        echo "<h1 class=head1> Result</h1>";
        $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
        echo "<Table align=center><tr class=tot><td>Total Question<td> $_SESSION[qn]";
        echo "<tr class=tans><td>True Answer<td>".$_SESSION[trueans];
        $w=$_SESSION[qn]-$_SESSION[trueans];
        echo "<tr class=fans><td>Wrong Answer<td> ". $w;
        echo "</table>";
        mysql_query("insert into mst_result(login,test_id,test_date,score) values('$login',$tid,'".date("d/m/Y")."',$_SESSION[trueans])") or die(mysql_error()); 
        mysql_query("insert into mst_adminresult(login,test_id,score) values('$login',$tid,$_SESSION[trueans])")  or die(mysql_error());
        unset($_SESSION[qn]);
        unset($_SESSION[sid]);
        unset($_SESSION[tid]);
        unset($_SESSION[trueans]);
        exit;
```

now i've added a timer

```
var c=10;
var t;
timedCount();

        function timedCount()
        {

            var hours = parseInt( c / 3600 ) % 24;
            var minutes = parseInt( c / 60 ) % 60;
            var seconds = c % 60;

            var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);


            $('#timer').html(result);
            if(c == 0 )
            {
                $('#myfm').submit();
            }
            c = c - 1;
            t = setTimeout(function()
            {
             timedCount()
            },
            1000);
        }
```

the problem is it won't submit. it just keeps on the same page. I first tried to check it by creating an alert box and it worked, making me sure that the timer code is working. So what could possibly be the solution for this, so that I can have the same process that it will show me my results and send the answers to my database?

Comment: try using quotes for your attribute values  `action=\"quiz.php\"`. Beyond that we need more detail on exactly what happens when you submit

Comment: what I want to get when the user clicks submit is, redirect the user to the result page. and store the details of the result in the db. @charlietfl

Comment: That doesn't explain what is currently happening exactly

Comment: so.. the problem only occured after you added the timer?

Comment: ah. the timer works. it counts down but, when it is finished, when it reached 00:00, nothing happens, the form won't submit. its just stays the way it is. @charlietfl

Comment: @C.oast yes. i was wondering if i could call a function to my php code and insert it in the javascript

Comment: okay.. besides the usage of mysql_ which i discourage, edit: saw it already but logically, yes, that is possible. i assume your timer is generic timer that forces the user out of the current page and automatically submit it? or...

Comment: I cannot gurantee my answer will be right, but are you sure that you are POST-ing correctly? i have never used such POST before. i dont think you can use such things as if $submit = 'getanswer'
you should use something like if $_POST['submit] or in this case, you will need to change your submit names to your POSTs

Comment: i'm kind of new to this, can you show me an example on how to it with my code? thank you. it would be a very great help. @C.oast

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112342/discussion-between-jennifer-and-c-oast).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<div class=\"module form-module\">";
echo "<form name=myfm class=form method=post id=myfm action=quiz.php>";
echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";
$n=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
echo "<tR><td><span class=style2>Question ".  $n .": $row[2]</style><br><br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=ans value=1>&nbsp;$row[3]<br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=ans value=2>&nbsp;$row[4]<br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=ans value=3>&nbsp;$row[5]<br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=ans value=4>&nbsp;$row[6]<br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=ans value=5>&nbsp;$row[7]<br>";
if($_SESSION[qn]<mysql_num_rows($rs)-1)
echo "<tr><td><br><input type=submit class=button id=submit name=next value='Next Question'></form></div>";
else
echo "<tr><td><input type=submit id=submit class=button name=results value='Get Result'></form></div>";
```

php

```
if($_POST['next'] && $_POST['ans'])
{           echo "Yay! You POST-ed!";
        mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
        $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs); 
        mysql_query("insert into mst_useranswer(sess_id, test_id, que_des, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,ans5,true_ans,your_ans) values ('".session_id()."', $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$row[8]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());
        if($ans==$row[8])
        {
                    $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
        }
        $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
}
else if($_POST['results'] && $_POST['ans'])
{        echo "Yay! You POST-ed!";
        mysql_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
        $row= mysql_fetch_row($rs); 
        mysql_query("insert into mst_useranswer(sess_id, test_id, que_des, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,ans5,true_ans,your_ans) values ('".session_id()."', $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$row[8]','$ans')") or die(mysql_error());
        if($ans==$row[8])
        {
                    $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
        }
        echo "<h1 class=head1> Result</h1>";
        $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
        echo "<Table align=center><tr class=tot><td>Total Question<td> $_SESSION[qn]";
        echo "<tr class=tans><td>True Answer<td>".$_SESSION[trueans];
        $w=$_SESSION[qn]-$_SESSION[trueans];
        echo "<tr class=fans><td>Wrong Answer<td> ". $w;
        echo "</table>";
        mysql_query("insert into mst_result(login,test_id,test_date,score) values('$login',$tid,'".date("d/m/Y")."',$_SESSION[trueans])") or die(mysql_error()); 
        mysql_query("insert into mst_adminresult(login,test_id,score) values('$login',$tid,$_SESSION[trueans])")  or die(mysql_error());
        unset($_SESSION[qn]);
        unset($_SESSION[sid]);
        unset($_SESSION[tid]);
        unset($_SESSION[trueans]);
        //you can use session_destory(); 
        exit;
```